# Can I prevent PropertyInfo.SetValue from removing leading newline?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = myObjectType.GetProperty(propName);
propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, "\n some text", null);
```

the result is myObject.propName = "some text"

thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it to know but you might attempt ```${Environment.Newline} some text}"```. I'm not sure why the \n with space is getting trumped here.  Not a PC to test it though.

Comment: can you show us the definition of the property you are trying to set?

Comment: thanks Lucifer! i didn't check the property and it has a value.Trim(); on the setter. d'oh!

Comment: i guess put it in an answer and i'll mark it?